# USE MAX( ) WITH SELECT column_name WITHOUT GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to SELECT MAX wickets with the NAME

`SELECT NAME, MAX(WICKETS) FROM BOWLER;`

but get this error
`not a single-group group function`

what should I do;

Comment: Why don't you want to use a group-by clause? There is an analytic version of max but if that's all you are selecting then you'd just see the same data repeated multiple times for each name.

Comment: SELECT NAME, MAX(WICKETS) FROM BOWLER group by Name

Answer (score 1):

Use an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT name,
       MAX(wickets) OVER () AS global_maximum,
       MAX(wickets) OVER (PARTITION BY name) AS name_maximum
FROM   bowler;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE bowler (name, match_id, wickets) AS
SELECT 'Alice', 1, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Alice', 2, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Alice', 3, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Beryl', 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Beryl', 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Beryl', 3, 0 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | NAME | GLOBAL_MAXIMUM | NAME_MAXIMUM |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Alice | 4 | 4 |
> | Alice | 4 | 4 |
> | Alice | 4 | 4 |
> | Beryl | 4 | 2 |
> | Beryl | 4 | 2 |
> | Beryl | 4 | 2 |

---

If you want to filter to only get the row that is a maximum for the name then:

```sql
SELECT name,
       match_id,
       global_maximum,
       name_maximum
FROM   (
  SELECT name,
         match_id,
         wickets,
         MAX(wickets) OVER () AS global_maximum,
         MAX(wickets) OVER (PARTITION BY name) AS name_maximum
  FROM   bowler
)
WHERE wickets = name_maximum;
```

Which outputs:

> | NAME | MATCH_ID | GLOBAL_MAXIMUM | NAME_MAXIMUM |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Alice | 3 | 4 | 4 |
> | Beryl | 1 | 4 | 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a4831a3d531f4bc2b90de96477857895)*

Answer (score 0):

Here's sample table:

```
SQL> select ename, sal from emp order by sal desc;

ENAME             SAL
---------- ----------
KING             5750       --> I presume you want KING, as his salary
FORD             3450           is greatest (i.e. MAX) in that data set
SCOTT            3450
JONES            3421
<snip>
```

If that's so, then

```
SQL> select a.ename, a.sal
  2  from emp a
  3  where a.sal = (select max(b.sal) from emp b);

ENAME             SAL
---------- ----------
KING             5750

SQL>
```

---

Query you posted presumes that there are several rows per each `name`, and you want to get MAX value of the `wickets` column per each `name` without `group by`. Why would you want that? `GROUP BY` *is* what you should be using, then.